# How to build a docker image in wsl2?

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I'm using docker in wsl2. I followed [this guide](https://dev.to/_nicolas_louis_/how-to-run-docker-on-windows-without-docker-desktop-hik) for the setup and everything covered therein seems to work.

Now when I try to build a docker image in wsl2 with `docker build .` I get the error `Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?`

I assume that I have to tell `docker build` on which IP the docker host is running (similar to `docker -H 172.20.5.64 run --rm hello-world`), but I have no idea how to do this?

Comment: If everything is set up correctly, the docker daemon port should be accessible under `localhost:2375` on the windows host. Thus, `docker build -H localhost:2375 ...` should work. If we do not want to enter the `-H localhost:2375`-part every time, we can set environment variable `DOCKER_HOST` to `localhost:2375`.

Comment: @Turing85 setting the ```DOCKER_HOST``` environment variable did work. ```docker build -H ...``` complains that the ```-H``` flag does not exist.

Comment: Yeah, true. `-H ...` must be set before `build`, i.e. `docker -H ... build ...`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, here is the solution, that worked for me:

1. I had to stop docker

```
sudo docker service stop
```

2. I had to start docker daemon

```
sudo dockerd
```

3. I had to stop docker daemon by pressing `ctrl + z`
4. Than i had to move the process in the background

```
bg %1
```

5. Then I was able to restart docker

```
sudo docker service start
```

After that, I did no longer get an error.
I hope this works for you too.